# How to right join with another query?

Tags: mysql

I need to count repeated rows but only show them in results if at least one of them has status = 'new'.

```
______________
URL  |  Status
--------------
A       new
A       seen
B       new
C       seen
```

should echo:

```
___________
URL  |  SUM
-----------
A       2 (counts both the seen one and the new one because there is at least one nwe)
B       1
```

My idea is basically to count the repeated URLs and RIGHT JOIN it with the same table but only rows with Status = 'new' so that remaining rows disappear.

```
SELECT `userFlags` distinct(URL) WHERE Status = "new"
```

How do I add these conditions to the joining table and how is it called?

EDIT

I added Status = "new" to the query, how can I add distinct(URL) or nest the whole query on it?

```
SELECT userFlags.URL, COUNT( * ) AS SUM
FROM  `userFlags`
RIGHT JOIN `userFlags` as u2 ON u2.Status = "new" AND userFlags.URL = u2.URL
GROUP BY u2.URL
ORDER BY SUM DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select userFlags.URL,Count(Status) AS SUM  from userFlags
where Status = "new" 
group by userFlags.URL
```

**Edit**

```
Select userFlags.URL,Count(Status) AS SUM  from userFlags
where userFlags.URL in 
    (Select userFlags.URL from  userFlags where Status = "new" )
group by userFlags.URL
```

Comment: Thanks, the thing is I need to count the "seen" rows too. If just one row has status "new" I need to count all the ones with the same URL, even if they aren't "new".

Comment: This will not work, as the condition will keep only rows where Status = new. Therefore, you'll miss a row when URL = 1, in OP's sample.

Comment: Yep, I read it, your answer is wrong. Your query returns the wrong SUM when URL = 1.

Comment: @Pranay Rana: Then your answer is just like Asaph's, why not delete it?

Comment: @Pranay Rana: I'm not saying you did, I'm saying your answer is no longer useful as it has already been posted by someone.

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is:

```
SELECT userFlags.URL, COUNT( * ) AS SUM
FROM  `userFlags`
JOIN (select distinct URL from userflags where status = 'new') as u2 on u2.url = userflags.url
GROUP BY u2.URL
ORDER BY SUM DESC **strong text**
```

Comment: thanks. This is exactly what I wanted to do. I'll accept on a minute.

Comment: Time goes by so slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an OUTER JOIN, do an INNER JOIN :

```
SELECT U1.URL, COUNT(*) AS Foo
FROM userFlags U1
INNER JOIN userFlags U2
    ON U1.URL = U2.URL
   AND U2.Status = 'new'
GROUP BY U1.URL;
```

If there is no row matching the join condition, then the row will not be added to the resultset. This filters out any URL that does not have at least one row where Status = new.

Edit: Removed the HAVING, for some reason I thought you only wanted rows where URL appeared more than once.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a right join. I think that's just complicating things for you. Using a subquery to find the 'new' rows is one strategy.

```
select u2.URL, count(*) as SUM
from userFlags as u2
where u2.URL in (
    select distinct u1.URL from userFlags as u1 where u1.Status = 'new'
) group by u2.URL;
```

Alternatively, this could be written as a join instead of a subquery.

```
select u2.URL, count(*) as SUM
from userFlags as u2
inner join (
    select distinct u1.URL from userFlags as u1 where u1.Status = 'new'
) as subq on subq.URL = u2.URL
group by u2.URL;
```

Either one works. Here is a quick test to prove it:

```
mysql> create table userFlags (
    -> URL varchar(255) not null,
    -> Status enum('new', 'seen') not null,
    -> index(URL),
    -> index(Status)
    -> ) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into userFlags (URL, Status) values ('A', 'new'), ('A', 'seen'), ('B', 'new'), ('C', 'seen');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from userFlags;
+-----+--------+
| URL | Status |
+-----+--------+
| A   | new    |
| A   | seen   |
| B   | new    |
| C   | seen   |
+-----+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select u2.URL, count(*) as SUM
    -> from userFlags as u2
    -> where u2.URL in (
    ->     select distinct u1.URL from userFlags as u1 where u1.Status = 'new'
    -> ) group by u2.URL;
+-----+-----+
| URL | SUM |
+-----+-----+
| A   |   2 |
| B   |   1 |
+-----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select u2.URL, count(*) as SUM
    -> from userFlags as u2
    -> inner join (
    ->     select distinct u1.URL from userFlags as u1 where u1.Status = 'new'
    -> ) as subq on subq.URL = u2.URL
    -> group by u2.URL;
+-----+-----+
| URL | SUM |
+-----+-----+
| A   |   2 |
| B   |   1 |
+-----+-----+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```